# Which Design Pattern does Apache wicket follow

Tags: wicket-1.6

I am new to wicket . could someone please tell me which design pattern does wicket follow in framework .

Answer (score 0):

It's the ultimate MVC.

Your front end people can literally work almost independently, with real HTML that doesn't have any code embedded in it... While the programmers are filling that same page with dynamic data.

Comment: Thanks.. just one more query can we simulate wicket under any Java Design pattern

Comment: By your comment I'm assuming you're a student or something because it sounds like you don't understand the question or the answer.
I may be wrong and I apologize if I'm offending you, but I think you maybe need to understand the questions you are asking and the answers people give you.

Asking questions is good, but it doesn't look to me like you have done even a little bit of work to understand what I already said.